# ActiveRecord updated_at error on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

When I manually set the `updated_at` field of my model in a controller as follows:

```
el = Model.find(id)
el.update(updated_at: Time.now, updated_by: "some_name")
```

The minutes of the `created_at` field change to match those of `updated_at`.

This does not happen when I write the above lines of code in the console.

Any ideas ?

**Edit:**

*Project background:*

- I am using Rails 5, and the mysql2 gem.
- The problem does not arise when I repeat the commands in the rails console.
- To preform the action, I make an ajax call to the server from the client, and the function in the controller performs the action.

**Update:**

The same thing happens when using:

```
el.update_attribute(:updated_by, "some_name")
```

Which should automatically handle the `updated_at` field.

**Command Line Output:**

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nbRr.png)

I do not see the `created_at` field get modified anywhere.

- Also, if relevant I am on Windows 7, 64 bit.

**Update 2:**

I pushed this project to a Heroku server and the bug does not persist. 
I can only conclude this is a Windows bug.

Comment: Why use `updated_at: Time.now`?

Comment: Because `updated_at` does not update otherwise..

Comment: I just did it in console and it definitely does update `updated_at`.

Comment: Right, my bad, confused it with `update_column()`

The problem of the `created_at()` minutes syncing still persists though.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the problem. With the information you provided, this probably isn't an answerable question.

Comment: Do you have server logs that show the database insertion for the created_at field?